# see an imageview created in Fxml at the java class by id

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a problem in **JavaFX** with **FXML** , i created an **ImageView** in **FXML** and gave it an id . how can i simply use the **ImageView** that i have created in **FXML** in the java class code ?

Comment: Did it not work to [inject it into the controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation) in the usual way? Post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the `ImageView` in your controller, you need to add the `@FXML` annotation before it.

An example in Java would be like so:

```java
@FXML
private Canvas canvas;
```

And in the FXML file:

```html
<center>
        <Canvas fx:id="canvas" height="600" width="600" />
</center>
```

**Just keep in mind that the name in Java *must* be the same as the `id` in the FXML file**

Comment: yes but i can't use it in any java class right ?
only the Controller class

Comment: From my knowledge, no you can't. However, you can insert nodes into a scene in your main class' `start()` method

Comment: will i made it in the Controller class , i am trying to type some kind of code in my program so i typed it in the Controller class but i get an Error each time i make an object to a specific class and assign it to it's constructor 
what seems the problem ?

Comment: The controller class is (mainly) used for `onAction` functions. If you're doing any Java GUI design, you would want to do it in the main java file

Comment: okay but in this case i won't be able to change an imageview while may code is running right ?

Comment: I don't think so. But thats worth testing out

Comment: Carter , thank you for your help . i have found a solution that i would like to share with you , which is you can edit any Control ( Label , ImageView , etc .. ) from any Java class not only through the controller class 
using the following code 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Label label = (Label) root.lookup("#ID");

Comment: Ah I didn't think of doing it that way. Nice!